# Adobe Brackets extensions installation

Tags: active-directory, emmet, adobe-brackets

I have brackets installed on my PC, but it's a client connect to an Active Directory domain.

Seems like a have some troubles installing Extensions like Emmet because my user directory is on domain server.

I've already check the rights on directory (i'm logged as Admin by the way), and i tried a manual install (upload .zip content into extensions directory and use npm install to install dependencies if necessary, but nothing seems to work properly.

Is there a way to change the Extensions directory in Brackets, or to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting [Brackets bug 8694](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/8694) – please watch that bug for updates.

The only way to change the extensions directory currently is to [clone Brackets from git](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets#quick-start) (simpler than you might think!) and modify `getUserExtensionPath()` to return a different path.